# Application-defined or object-defined error for formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the following code to input a formula but for some reason I get an application defined / object defined error for the 'iferror' formula I'm using.

```
ws_catalogue.Range("D3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Test Input'!$E:$E,MATCH(CONCATENATE([@Actor],[@Entity],D$1),'Test Input'!$A:$A,0)),"""")"
ws_catalogue.Range("D3:N3").FillRight
ws_catalogue.Range("D3:N" & Total_cat).FillDown
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are these fields in a table (list object): `[@Actor],[@Entity]`? if so, write the formula manually so it actually works, then translate that into your code. This is not working because you have no other list object (data table) reference for Excel to know what you are talking about. Either make the entire formula based on the table structure or none of it.

Comment: Take your formula (un-escape the double quotes), paste it into `D3`. Can Excel compute it? No? Fix it, paste the fixed version back into your code (re-escape the double quotes).

Comment: Thanks both - managed to fix it by changing the [@Actor] etc to the actual cells as suggested. Not sure how to mark correct answer here?